# Change height of Value Box in flexdashboard with runtime: shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I want a Value Box to adjust to the specified height and width of the section. There is no problem with the width, however it is taller than specified. Also I want only a specific Value Box to change size, so the rest of the Value Boxes remain the same.

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Dashboard_F"

output:
 flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
social: [ "twitter", "facebook", "menu"]
source_code: embed
css: www/styles.css

runtime: shiny
---

Column {data-width=275}
----------------------------------
### 2019 {data-height=50}
``` {r}
renderValueBox({
  valueBox(currency(sum(as.numeric(data()$`TOTAL (2019)`),na.rm=T),digits = 0),caption = "Total" ,color = "blue",icon="fa-money-bill")
})
```
````

I have tried changing the height by using css

````
```{css my-content, echo = FALSE}
.value-box {
    height: 5%;
}
```
````

This works but only for the box, it doesn´t adjust the icon or the caption, using font-size doesn´t seem to have any effect. Additionaly it affects all of the Value Boxes in the dashboard.

Is there any way to solve this? I would really aprecciate any help, thanks! :)

Comment: To check all libraries are included in your example before posting, please test it after restarting R

Comment: Hi! This are the libraries I am using:             ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "ES_ES.UTF-8")
library(flexdashboard)
library(knitr)
library(DT)
library(rpivotTable)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(openintro)
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggvis)
library(geojsonio)
library(rgdal)
library(shiny)
library(formattable)
library(reshape2)
```  I have already tried restarting R and nothing changed...

Comment: I doubt all these libraries are used in your sample. please specify which package contains `currency` function

Comment: There are more sections than what I showed in the example, I didn´t show all of them because they were not relevant for my problem, but alll the libraries are used in the complete code. The currency function is contained in the "formattable"  package. :)

Comment: Was this problem ever solved or did you by chance figure it out? It would be great to see a solution for this.